# Debounce holding a key pressed (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, accessibility, tabindex, debouncing

is there a way to debounce holding a key (in React if it changes anything, I am aware that I need to wrap debounce in useCallback)?

I have a few selects, each of them sends request. There's a default possibility to hold tab to go through selects, so there are too many requests being sent.

Can I set debounce on holding tab key? Also I'd prefer a solution which doesn't affect a11y.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you put your tried piece of code to understand more about it, please

Comment: It's a lot of components actually, but it doesn't matter - I would like isolated solution to debounce default tab behavior when hold or rapidly pressed

Comment: What triggers the requests? Please provide a minimal example. Sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/364724) to me.

Comment: Focusing on the select triggers the request, so I want prevent tab from focusing when holding key pressed

Comment: What is the purpose of the request? Fetching the available options for that select?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. It's kept in state in React

Comment: Unless you know that the options change very very frequently I'd suggest that you fetch the options only once on mounting the selects instead of every time you focus them. Alternatively you would have to debounce the handler that fetches the option and use a leading debounce, like [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce)'s `_debounce(myFn, 5000, {leading: true, trailing: false})` which will prevent firing the handler again in the specified timeout.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't fetch it once, because in each select different payload is sent to DB, because it's about different user, or can I?

Comment: @AniaKowalska Of course you can. You could fetch the options once on mount and keep it in react state for each select. I don't know what you mean with "it's about different user". It's hard to provide an exact answer without seeing any code.

Comment: Each select holds data for a different, so if I fetch them all at start the effect will be even worse, because I will make those request all at the same time

Comment: @AniaKowalska What is the problem with performing a few requests at the same time? This is absolutely no problem for the browser or the server. Without knowing any details about your use-case. If you really want to fetch on focus then go with a leading (+ maybe trailing) debounce with a reasonable timeout. It's not possible to provide a working example without knowing how your select components look like.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to hold the fetch by waiting a while, then checking if my select is the current document select, then fire the fetch or not

```
const sleep = (milliseconds = 500) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds));

const handleFocus = async () => {
  await sleep();
  if (selectRef.current === document.activeElement) {
    if (!listShowed) {
      showList(true);
      document.addEventListener('click', hideList);
    }
    fetch();
  }
};
```

But needed to add ref. Not sure if it's the most optimal solution, but it works.
If I change selected item rapidly, then after sleep() the selectRef.current !=== document.activeElement, so it won't fire